# Inconsistency in adjacent sibling selector between 1.5.1 and 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="t-dropzone">
        <input id="files" >
    </div>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#files').parents('.t-dropzone:first + ul')
```

In the case of `jquery-1.5.1.min.js` it returns a `ul` element, but `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` returns `null`.

Which of the library contains an error?

Answer (score 2):

That statement should return an empty jQuery object. You are looking for an ancestor of `#files` that matches `.t-dropzone:first + ul`, so that ancestor would have to be a `ul` element, of which there are none.

In slightly more detail, that selector would find a `ul` element that immediately follows the first `.t-dropzone` element. The first `.t-dropzone` element is an ancestor of `#files`, and it is immediately followed by a `ul`, but that `ul` is not a parent of of `#files`, so it shouldn't be returned.

Therefore, to answer your question, jQuery 1.5.1 (and below) contains the error, and it was fixed in jQuery 1.7.1 (as far as I can tell by changing the jQuery version on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/47zNV/)).

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way. You need to select the `div` first and then get its `ul` sibling:

```
$('#files').closest('.t-dropzone').next('ul')
```

See [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782951/298479) for a detailed explanation why.